# why does the touchable opacity onPress not trigger?

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue where my onPress of a touchable opacity doesn't fire. I am sure it isn't working because nothing console logs to the system when I press it.

My button component:

```
const FloatingPlusButton = (props) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.tapToAddEvent}>
          <MaterialIcons
            name='add'
            size={45}
            color='#28313b'
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
};
```

Where I call it:

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textInput: '',
      inputVisible: true
    };
  }

  onFloatingButtonPress() {
    this.setState({ inputVisible: true }, () => { this.textInputField.focus(); });
    console.log('p');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, height: HEIGHT }}>
        { !this.state.inputVisible &&
          <FloatingPlusButton tapToAddEvent={this.onFloatingButtonPress.bind(this)} />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

To be clear I do see the button and the inputVisible prop is not the issue. Just nothing happens when I press it. I tried it with both the .bind(this) and without it and neither worked.

Comment: try giving MaterialIcons width and height

Comment: you can't. I tried adding it to the touchable opacity but that didnt work either

Comment: I had this in a different component before and it worked fine, I really have no idea why it isn't working now

Comment: how is your `HEIGHT` defined? if it is undefined, when you press the button, do you see a change in its opacity?

Comment: I tried that, still nothing. For what it's worth this was inside of another child component and I'm moving it out to the parent. Nothing changed except I moved it from where it was. Code looks the exact same so I'm really not sure why the pressing doesn't work.

Comment: And no I don't. It isn't being pressed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I had to make the zIndex of the button greater than the zIndex of the root view component. Thanks for the help everybody.